# Consider creating a tag for the arcade game Pokemon Tretta

Tags: support, tags, pokemon, tag-creation

I was about to ask a question about Pokemon Tretta in Arqade, but I realized that there is no tag for it.

I was guided to ask here for a tag creation since I'm not yet able to create one.

Answer (score 4):

Ask the question anyway using an as close to approximate tag (in this case[pokemon-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-series) would do nicely) and

- mention the title in the question (ie. in *Pokemon Tretta* _______) and/or
- at the end make a request for a tag (ie. request [pokemon-tretta](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-tretta) as i do not have enough rep to create it)

someone with [the privilege](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) will very likely comes across the question and edit in the new tag.

remember that tags need to be used in a question as such can't be created ahead of time and need to be linked to a question (baring recently orphaned tags pending automatic removal)